# Can we have the existing Chat room "migrated" to the Beta site now that it is live?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, chat

Many of us have enjoyed discussing this proposal for several months now, at this chat room, called "[Materials Modeling Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104555/materials-modeling-chat)"

Now that the site is live, we also have [this one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107323/materials-modeling).

I wonder if the existing chat room can be transferred so that the "chat" button at the  bottom of this page, links us there?

Comment: I don't think this will be necessary, I am not sure this is possible. The main chat room of every site has special attributes (it doesn't go inactive). One could transfer all the messages, but that is a lot of work. Also, they should theoretically serve different purposes. If anything important came up in the old one, and that hasn't been dealt with, it may be worth having the discussion here instead.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, chat rooms parented to Area 51 cannot be reparented. In any case, it looks like you already have a new room — you can always leave a message on the old one pointing there, so that any lost soul can find their way to the new, active room instead :)

Comment: [**Actually chat rooms can be re-parented**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61605225#61605225).